# C++ - Custom build events

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build-events

Is there any way to force `Clean` action as a **Post / Pre build event** for *single* project in Visual Studio?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

1. right-click on your project in Solution Explorer and click Properties
2. go to Build events, then Pre-Build Events
3. put

   del /F /Q $(TargetDir)*.*

   in command line section.

Comment: Hm, nice. In my case this would be $(IntDir) actually, but thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This pre-build event works too :

```
devenv ${ProjectFileName} /Clean
```